# Integration with complex infinity

Tags: definite-integrals, complex-integration

I'm struggling to solve this problem.

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-a(x+di)^2} dx
$$

I tried

$$
t = \sqrt{a}(x+di)
$$
$$
=> dt = \sqrt{a}dx
$$
$$
=> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t^2}}{\sqrt{a}} dt
$$
since $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx = \sqrt{\pi}$,

$$
=> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t^2}}{\sqrt{a}} dt = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} 
$$
$$
=> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-a(x+di)^2} dx  = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} 
$$

However, I have found that complex infinity has only magnitude without arguments.
It means I can't regard domain of t as (-$\infty$,$\infty$) when $t = \sqrt{a}(x+di)$ and $x(-\infty, \infty)$.

And I found the correct answer is $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{ad^2}$.
How can I reach to this answer? I lost my way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way I like to do it, avoiding contour integration.  Fix a real number $a>0$.  Define a function of a complex variable $k$ by
$$
F(k) := \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(-a(x+k)^2\right)\;dx
$$
When $k$ is real, do the change of variables suggested (the real line maps to the real line for that change of variables) to get
$$
F(k) = \sqrt\frac{\pi}{a} \qquad \text{if } k \in \mathbb R.
$$
Next, from Morera's theorem, $F$ is an entire function of the complex variable $k$.  Therefore
$$
F(k) = \sqrt\frac{\pi}{a} \qquad \text{if } k \in \mathbb C.
$$

---

Your assertion about "the correct answer" is wrong.  Your answer is actually for
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(-a(x^2+(id)^2)\right)\;dx = \sqrt\frac{\pi}{a}\;e^{ad^2}
$$